# Typescript how to infer Literal types or string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So I am trying to get an object based on the parameter being passed in.
I found this question and it get really close to what I after.
[TypeScript function return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)
However, I want the function to be able to accept string too, and when the parameters passed in is not in the literal type, it will infer `any or unknown`

Let me put what I mean in code.

```js
interface Circle {
    type: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

interface Square {
    type: "square";
    length: number;
}

type TypeName = "circle" | "square" | string; 

type ObjectType<T> = 
    T extends "circle" ? Circle :
    T extends "square" ? Square :
    unknown;

function getItems<T extends TypeName>(type: T) : ObjectType<T>[]  {
    ...
}
```

Notice that `TypeName` has union type of literal type and string.
What I hope to see if that, when I use the type, I would be able to infer the return type based on the parameter. For example:

```js
const circle = getItems('circle'); // infers: Circle
const something = getItems('unknown'); // infers: unknown
```

The above is all good. However, I could not get the IDE to suggest the options.
I expect to see an options of: `'circle' | 'square' | string`.

Is that possible to do?

Comment: If you remove the `| string` option in `TypeName` it should work in your IDE. Or you can add something like `type TypeName = "circle" | "square" | "unknown"; `

Comment: Yes. But, it will have type error when I put the string 'unknown' in the param. I expect the function to infers `unknown` type.

Comment: following [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bird-b5my8?file=/src/index.ts) there seems to be no type error and if you hover over the called function it has the right type, am i missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Stutje. The type in the example is `type TypeName = "circle" | "square" | "unknown";`. However, I want `type TypeName = "circle" | "square" | string;`, the actual `string` type. The reason behind it is that if the type is not Literal Type that I specified, I would like to use the type value as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible because `string` is super type of string literal so

```
type TypeName = "circle" | "square" | string;
```

is no different than

```
type TypeName = string;
```

However, you could use function overloading to achieve your goal

```
type TypeName = "circle" | "square"
type ObjectType<T> = 
    T extends "circle" ? Circle :
    T extends "square" ? Square :
    never

function getItems<T extends TypeName>(type: T) : ObjectType<T>[]
function getItems(type: string) : unknown[]
function getItems(type: string) {
  // implementation comes here
}
```

anyway, here's a new hack

```
type TypeName = "circle" | "square" | {} & string; 

type ObjectType<T> = 
    T extends "circle" ? Circle :
    T extends "square" ? Square :
    unknown;

function getItems<T extends TypeName>(type: T) : ObjectType<T>[]  {
    ...
}
```

try it yourself

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer @Austraras. However, the solution doesn't look like it's working. I created a [codepen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-sanne-di2wu?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: you missed 2nd overload and go directly to implentation

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using overloads and a few conditional utility types:

```
interface Circle {
    type: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

interface Square {
    type: "square";
    length: number;
}


type KnownObject = Circle | Square
type IsKnownTypeName<T extends string, U = KnownObject> = U extends { type: T } ? T : never
type ObjectForType<T extends string, U = KnownObject> = U extends { type: T } ? U : never

function getItems<T extends string>(type: IsKnownTypeName<T>) : ObjectForType<T>[]
function getItems<T extends string>(type: T) : any[]
function getItems<T extends string>(type: T) : any[] {
    return []
}

const circle = getItems('circle'); // infers: Circle
const something = getItems('unknown'); // infers: any
```