# Let typescript know based on the input paramater what the output type is

Tags: typescript

I have this function that returns an object or a string, simplified it looks like this:

```
const data = {
    a: 'x',
    b: 'y'
};

function getData(key?: string): Record<string, string> | string {
    return key ? data[key] : data;
}
```

So, what this means is that if you call this function with a **key**

```
const out = getData('b'); // => 'y' (string)
console.log(out.toUpperCase()); // => typescript error
```

[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF2AEwIZ2QLmAJQKaQE6IA88+AllAOYA0wpFlAfMALzADeAUKD8BsAHIAHgOrdeIAEaYBATwHiQAXwDcnRSABmAVyhg4ZaMEo44AEVTIAFAGscsgPyZ6VAJSZcBYi5p045KmYAHz8Ayg4NHjJNYFt7VwiJCXxTbXwoJEsAbTtZAF0+GFCGNSTgJWAcABsYHESykBS4NIyUNELsPAhCEn8GWh9mUqSlDVGNSFgECG0ENhNzSysBSQFXYZBJmAgqnAA6KohKKxm4PbgIAFUAB2ucfABhZFqrV3X1IA)

It is needed here to tell typescript what the type of **out** is, an **Record<string, string>** or just a **string**.

So my question is, is it possible to somehow let typescript know that when you have specified a **key** that it will always be a **string**  and otherwise a **Record**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript function return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)

Comment: DEMO link is broken

Comment: Yes thanks, overload signatures did the trick :) [DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF2AEwIZ2QLmAJQKaQE6IA88+AllAOYA0wpFlAfMALzADeAUKD8BsAHIAHgOrdeIAEaYBATwHiQAXwDcnRSABmAVyhg4ZaMEo44AEVTIAFAEpMuAsXpVazpmt469BoyfOWrAGscWUw3Ozo4cioPHi99QyhjUws0IJCAfjCohgiHCEISHJdI6KZgAB9Shg4NHjJNYHTZG1qJCXxTbXwklDQAbWDZAF0+GGqYutAlYBwAGxgcNvbQTrhu3ssx7DwCp2KaCfLYiSUNM41IWAQIbQQ2P1TrAUkBGxPwaBgIOZwAOjmEEoVlucD+cAgAFUAA7QnD4ADCyEWtne6iAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with some help of [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```js
const data = {
    a: 'x',
    b: 'y'
};

type Data = typeof data

function getData<T extends keyof Data>(key: T):Data[T]
function getData<T extends keyof Data>():Data
function getData<T extends keyof Data>(key?: T) {
    return key ? data[key] : data;
}

const result = getData('a') // string
const result2 = getData('b') // string
const result3 = getData() // Data
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAsAKBvmBALhgHIAPUgGlwJgCMTSBPU3AXwG5dcpmAHAKYwAIkhTo%20QkADN44njhkBXMMCgBLcDADmgqGOQAeACoxB5KILBwIMANaDms0eIB8ACkfMSJgJREhggA2iYAurgqapraegbipuaW1rYOTi5BngFBkarqWmC6%20kGJFlY2dt4Z7l5OAPy%20fpi0BABO%20sqthd4wdfLIwd5hMCSIyNw47IqgkLDtEMoANrDocUEepAikTQD0OzDQrRpgOrgz0DDzS1AATGhF8cgb9NswewdQRydn4BdXywBme5rcQeXb7IJAA)