# How to get object property values as type from a function argument

Tags: typescript

here is the short example of what I am trying to achieve

```
type Arg = {
  name: string
}

function fun(arg: Arg): // what do I return ? 
function fun (arg) {
  return {[arg.name]: true}
}
```

is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Would you like to set the output of `fun`? Could you describe more about the question?

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: @MajidMohammadi sorry, I thought it was obvious from the code example. 

I want to set the return type of function fun. 

for example: `fun({ name: 'John'})` will return `{John: true}` I don't know how to describe this kind of output in typescript

Comment: I guess you want to return type based on your input, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54166010/10321531) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for smth like this:

```js
type Arg<T extends string> = {
    name: T
}

function fun<Name extends string, T extends Arg<Name>>(arg: T): Record<T['name'], boolean>
function fun<Name extends string, T extends Arg<Name>>(arg: T) {
    return { [arg.name]: true }
}

const result = fun({ name: 'John' }) // Record<"John", boolean>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwDwBUoQB7AgOwCYDOUBwcAljggHxQC8UA3gLABQU7UOAhgLYQBcUFKwC%20rVgDMArjgDGwMgHscUaTiQA5XtEzZ8REuUoAaIeiy5CsRJu1UqACi6JBKAJSCAShFmK4eVABtAHJuPmCAXVMAI0VFABsILhwqSRl5JRU1Wz5zPStDCgRTNF1LInhkLT57JxchN0ZWDig4CGApOBUGKEDnBAA6MIgIwVIpaDEWKdZfHBJWiAIpeOA6VRkHHuHBYIApRQALHGCoEUaAeguob19-JAAiA%20OHmLjE5KogA)

More about infering function arguments, you can find [in my article](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/typescript-type-inference-on-function-arguments-2n93)