# TS typing according to variable using typemap

Tags: typescript, interface, typing

my goal is to have a Packet interface with a property id that will serve to determine what the type of the packet is. The end goal is to use this in a network program and call functions to handle each different packet.

This is is what I currently have for my packets.

```
export interface Packet {
    id: number;
}

export interface PacketTypeMap {
    1: PacketA;
    2: PacketB;
}


export interface PacketA extends Packet {
    additionalData: string,
}

export interface PacketB extends Packet {
    otherKeys: string
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to use this code to call a function according to the type.
I thought that something like this would work:

```
const funcPtrs = {
    1: (packet: PacketA) => {console.log("Packet A")},
    2: (packet: PacketB) => {console.log("Packet B")}
}

let unknownTypePacket: Packet = {id: 2, otherKeys: "data"}
type packetType = PacketTypeMap[unknownTypePacket.id];
let knownPacketType: PacketTypeMap[packetType] = unknownTypePacket;

funcPtrs[unknownTypePacket.id](knownPacketType);
```

This has a few problems:

- I can't declare the "unknownTypePacket" variable because it has the "otherKeys" property, which a Packet doesn't have
- The second problem is that on line 7 it says "Type 'unknownTypePacket.id' cannot be used as an index type.", I've tried looking for this problem and saw that it could have something to do with using "Number" instead of "number", but that isn't the case here.

You should also know that I'm still pretty new to Typescript and haven't wrapped my head around the "key of" operators explained in the documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

Any help will be appreaciated, thanks !

**EDIT:**
I've came accross this page which is close to what I want, but the circles object isn't actually typed by typescript and their getItems function returns an array of objects, and in my case I just want to return a type of one of my packets

[TypeScript function return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Not everything you are trying to do here is possible.

But let's start with the `funcPtrs`:

```
type AllPackets = PacketA & PacketB

const funcPtrs: Record<number, (packet: AllPackets) => void> = {
    1: (packet: PacketA) => {console.log("Packet A")},
    2: (packet: PacketB) => {console.log("Packet B")}
}
```

We create a combined type `AllPackets` which contains all different Packet-types. We will give the function the type of `Record<number, /*...*/>`. Now it can be indexed correctly with:

```
funcPtrs[unknownTypePacket.id](knownPacketType);
```

---

I think the next two lines are impossible to do:

```
type packetType = PacketTypeMap[unknownTypePacket.id];
let knownPacketType: PacketTypeMap[packetType] = unknownTypePacket;
```

You are trying to create a `type` here but this can only done with information that is known at compile-time which `unknownTypePacket.id` is not.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, how would you approach this system if I can't have a known type ?
And the functions "(packet: PacketA) => {console.log("Packet A")}" aren't accepted in the funcPtrs variable because they aren't compatible with the "Packet" Type

Comment: I edited my answer. You need a joined Type of all Packets which I called `AllPackets`

Comment: I think a better way to do this would be to use `class` instead of just TypeScript types. You will than also know in runtime which sub-class each Packet belongs to.