# Typescript return type based on value of object property

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code that is somewhat based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54166010/9991191) to a similar question:

```
interface A {
    type: "a";
    data: string;
}

interface B {
    type: "b";
    data: string;
}

type Helper<T extends A | B> = 
    T["type"] extends A["type"] ? A : 
    T["type"] extends B["type"] ? B : 
    never;
    
const get = <T extends A | B>({ type }: Pick<T, "type">): Helper<T> => {

    return {
        type,
        data: type,
    } as Helper<T>;

};

const mySelected = get({ type: "a" });
console.log(mySelected);
```

my `get` function should return an object of type `A` if the first arguments type is `a` and one of type `B` if its first arguments type is "b".
In my code however `mySelected` has the type never.
If I change the function call to `get<A>({ type: "a" })` I get the correct type of `A`, but I would like Typescript to figure this out on its own. Furthermore, if I change the function call to `get<B>({ type: "a" })`, Typescript notices that something is wrong and complains that `Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.`.

Comment: The answer you linked is indeed very similar. Why don't you use any solutions, which are mentioned there?

Comment: @TobiasS. I am trying to, but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bases upon [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter/54166010#54166010) you linked:

```js
interface A {
    type: "a";
    data: string;
}

interface B {
    type: "b";
    data: string;
}

const get = <T extends Pick<A | B, 'type'>>({ type }: T ) => {
    return {
        type,
        data: type,
    } as    T extends Pick<A, 'type'> ? A :
            T extends Pick<B, 'type'> ? B :
            never
};

const mySelectedA = get({ type: "a" }); // const mySelectedA: A
const mySelectedB = get({ type: "b" }); // const mySelectedB: B
const mySelectedC = get({ type: "c" }); // const mySelectedC: never | Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.(2322)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use intersection types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

```js
interface A {
    type: "a";
    data: string;
}

interface B {
    type: "b";
    data: string;
}

type MyType = A | B

const myVar: MyType = {type: "a", data:"data"}
```