# function return type based on input type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, conditional-types

it is similar question to [TypeScript function return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter) but i don't understand how it works with promises.
input is string or string[]
if is string then method returns PlaylistEntity
else array of them

```
type TypeName = string | string[]
type ObjectType<T> = Promise<T extends string ? PlaylistEntity : PlaylistEntity[]>
```

```
    async get<T extends TypeName>(playlists: T): ObjectType<T>{
        try {
            const col = collection(firestore, 'playlists')
            if(Array.isArray(playlists)){
                const fetchArray = playlists.slice(0, 10)
                const q = query(col, where('__name__', 'in', fetchArray))
                const docs = await getDocs(q)
                return docs.docs.map(v => {return {id: v.id, ...v.data()} as PlaylistEntity})
            }
            else{
                const docRef = await getDoc(doc(col, playlists))
                return {id: docRef.id, ...docRef.data()} as PlaylistEntity
            }
        }catch (e) {
            throw new HttpException(e.message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
```

error TS2322: Type 'PlaylistEntity' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? PlaylistEntity : PlaylistEntity[]'.

43                 return {id: docRef.id, ...docRef.data()} as PlaylistEntity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) can help you with modeling your TS types?

```
// Some dummy interface.
interface PlaylistEntity {
    id: string
};

// When caller passes string[], returned promise resolves to PlaylistEntity[].
async function getPlaylistEntries(playlists: string[]): Promise<PlaylistEntity[]>;

// When caller passes string, returned promise resolves to PlaylistEntity.
async function getPlaylistEntries(playlists: string): Promise<PlaylistEntity>;

// Single implementation satisfying both overloads.
async function getPlaylistEntries(playlists: string | string[]) {
    try {
        if (Array.isArray(playlists)){
            return playlists.map((p: string) => ({id: "some-id"}));
        }
        else{
            return {id: "some-id"};
        }
    }catch (e) {
        throw new Error();
    }
}

// onePlaylistEntry inferred type is Promise<PlaylistEntity>
const onePlaylistEntry = getPlaylistEntries("a")

// arrOfPlayListEntries inferred type is Promise<PlaylistEntity[]>
const arrOfPlayListEntries = getPlaylistEntries(["a"])
```

Check ^this in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIAKAbJBPbMAZygFFowo90BvUdB9MAEwC50S5IBzUAXwDcoUEiJ4IKdAgCuEqGAD2EdNxhQc+QiXJQuMIgAoADrgLEoRdpx4BtALoBKdpjgKAtsRgAeDWe0UqewA+IRBRcUkZOUVlVXVTLTJoPUMTTXNLDl0eJyxXDyJvX0SdSjwQ4TCxCSlZFHklFTVi8x0UrwAVIOMEjPYOh1p6Rl1qOhBGSaYEdAMAQTg4fAA6YgWlvB70kiIHB3Gpw-Q4NWk4ZTS-C2W3JCMDYytsiG5BgF4g2ZoWdgAiIncMAAtCxfnw9qEjug+MNDjBsIUDlDGCcoGdlN82Oh-oCQcwwZCjjCJow+CgkFAUAALWYwQZIw5QKmuADu6AgMDZpEWCjgBgchIYxOJoBQShI6CUMBa-lG6DeTXi2yS2X0Bl+SF+DlF4qg6CQiwA8ghfAAZVrJMD6eWKmUqlIGGwa36OIA).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But please add the code to your answer directly and add a few sentences explaining how and why it works here.

Comment: Also I think the generic on the implementation is confusing and [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8ELVN) would be cleaner.

Comment: @AlexWayne thanks for your comment - updated my answer. +1 for dropping generic in favour of explicit `string | string[]` that was my neglect

Comment: that's much easier to understand than conditional types