# Create typescript function which guarantees return type based on input type

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have created the below function which retrieves either Users or Addresses from my database

```
type Q = User | Address

export async function b(entityClass: EntityTarget<Q>, em: EntityManager, ids: number[]): Promise<Q[]> {
  const e = await em.findBy(entityClass, { id: In(ids) });
  return e
}
```

In my example if `entityClass` is `User` the function only guarantees to either return `User[]` or `Address[]`. However I would like the function to guarantee that if `entityClass` is `User` then the function will always return `User[]`.

(The `EntityTarget` and `EntityManager` are from typeorm, I'm leaving it in as I'm not sure if it will be relevant to answering the question)

I've looked at some other solutions on stackexchange (in particular this one [TypeScript function return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)) but I don't understand how to apply them to my problem

How can I do this

---

Edit: when I try:

```
async function b<EntityType extends Q>(entityClass: EntityTarget<EntityType>, em: EntityManager, ids: number[]): Promise<EntityType[]> {
  const e = await em.findBy(entityClass, { id: In(ids) });
  return e
}
```

I get the problem:

```
Argument of type '{ id: FindOperator<any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOptionsWhere<EntityType> | FindOptionsWhere<EntityType>[]'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'FindOperator<any>' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhereProperty<NonNullable<EntityType["id"]>>'
```

on the part where I write `{ id: In(ids) }`

Comment: The search keyword you're looking for is "generics".

Comment: The thing is I feel like I tried every permutation of adding angle brackets union types conditional types etc. but it still does not work.... Any chance you might have  a moment to give a deeper insight? Sorry if this seems like a trivial question...

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your question, this simple generic function, without conditional, should be enough (I've removed some parameters for brevity): `function b<EntityType extends Q>(entityClass: EntityTarget<EntityType>): Promise<EntityType[]>`.

Comment: @Blackhole I've tried that - I added the error I get from this approach above now

Comment: That's a whole other question: the problem comes from the ORM here, and I've never used this one and so can't be helpful. The cast to `R[]` is suspicious, though. What is it? Shouldn't it depend on `EntityType`, something like `EntityType["id"]`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the cast to R thing both in the example above as well as in my code but that was not causing the Error

Comment: I was thinking that it might have to do with the ORM but then why does it work in my first example and not in the solution you suggested...?

Comment: Still think that `ids` shouldn't be `number[]` but something like `EntityType["id"][]`. But again, I've never work with this ORM so I can't help further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248737/discussion-between-sev-and-blackhole).

Comment: Sorry to keep asking you... but could the problem be that Address and User are classes and we make an EntityType type out of them?

Comment: I've reduced this problem to a pure typescript problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74033462/typescript-passes-type-differently-to-function-when-using-generic if you would like to have a look