# Typescript passes type differently to function when using generic

Tags: typescript

I have the following piece of code

```
// Address and User are two classes, bothe of which have an id
type Q = Address | User

// This works just fine 
async function c<EntityType = Q>(ids: Q["id"][]) {
}

// This gives me the error described bellow
async function c<EntityType = Q>(ids: EntityType["id"][]) {
}
```

The problem I get if I use the second function definition is:

```
Type '"id"' cannot be used to index type 'EntityType'
```

Further when I in vscode hover over ids in the first function I get `(parameter) ids: number[]` (Which is expected as Q.id is a number) but if I hover over ids in the second function I get `ids: EntityType["id"][]`

How can I fix this problem??

Comment: A call like `c<{hello: string}>(someArray)` will not work with the second definition. Or even `c<string>(someArray)`. Remember that it's *the caller* who determines the generic type argument. You cannot assume that it will be any specific thing when you have not constrained it.

Comment: @VLAZ would you mind elaborating how I could constrain this in my related post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74033593/typescript-resolves-type-differently-when-passed-as-generic? It seems I made a wrong assumption in the post above which Dylan picked up on

Comment: It's exactly the same answer. You still have unconstrained `EntityType` in the second case. You still just need to constrain it with `extends`. It's basically the same problem. Just different manifestation.

Comment: Sorry copy paste error - I fixed it now

Comment: a good practice that might help is instead of making `Q` a union of your classes, make `Q` an inferface which includes `id: number` as a property and have your classes implement `Q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you set the generic to type `Q` by default, the generic could still be any. To fix this, you need to limit the type of the generic by using the `extends` keyword like so:

```js
async function c<EntityType extends Q>(ids: EntityType["id"][]) {
}
```