# Typescript resolves type differently when passed as generic

Tags: typescript

I have the following piece of code

```
// Address and User are two classes, bothe of which have an id
type Q = Address | User

// This works just fine 
async function c<EntityType extends Q>(ids: Q["id"][]) {
}

// This gives me the error described bellow
async function c<EntityType extends Q>(ids: EntityType["id"][]) {
}
```

When I in vscode hover over ids in the first function I get `(parameter) ids: number[]` (Which is expected as Q.id is a number) but if I hover over ids in the second function I get `ids: EntityType["id"][]`

This is leading to errors downstream... Why is this happening and how can I gix this?

---

Edit: Adding the aforementioned errors:

In the function I am using the line

```
  const e = await em.findBy(entityClass, { id: In(ids) });
```

And typescript complains:

```
Argument of type '{ id: FindOperator<any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOptionsWhere<EntityType> | FindOptionsWhere<EntityType>[]'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'FindOperator<any>' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhereProperty<NonNullable<EntityType["id"]>>'
```

On `{id: In(ids)}` (entityClass is of type EntityType)

Comment: could you elaborate on "errors downstream"

Comment: I don't see a problem with this https://tsplay.dev/ND2yjW What exactly is the error you have?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after searching around, I found that you were using typeorm. Instead of having `Q` be a union of the classes you define. You should make it an interface in which classes can implement, which I've renamed `EntityType` based on your generic. The resulting code would be:

```js
interface EntityType {
    id: number;
}

class Address implements EntityType {
    id: number;
    // your code
}

class User implements EntityType {
    id: number;
    // your code
}

async function b<T extends EntityType>(entityClass: EntityTarget<T>, em: EntityManager, ids: number[]): Promise<T[]> {
    const e = await em.findBy(entityClass as EntityTarget<EntityType>, { id: In(ids) });
    return e as T[];
}
```

Comment: Will this also work if I do: `async function b<T extends EntityType>(entityClass: EntityTarget<T>, em: EntityManager, ids: number[]): Promise<T[]> {`

Comment: hmm not sure why typeorms type declarations seem to complain when the input is generic. However, it should be safe to cast it within the function so typescript can stop complaining. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: When I do this it does unfortunately not remove the error I am getting...