# TypeScript function: 2nd arg type based on 1st arg value

Tags: typescript, types

I am creating a function to view data from 1 of 3, each category has its own unique list of headings.

The function has two args: `function openReport(category , report)`

With types, I want to the category value to be the condition to set the report type.

```
type reportCategory= 'financial' | 'operational' | 'security'

type financialReports = 'financial workspaces' | 'financial datacenter'
type operationalReports = 'operational information' | 'operational environment'
type securityReports = 'security Accounts' | 'security needing attention'

  const openReport async (
    catagory: reportCategory
    report: financialReports | operationalReports | securityReports,
  ) => {

  }
```

The way its currently set up is that the report could be set to be a value that will not correspond with the category and will fail down the line.

I want it so that when you set the category, the report type will be set to one of three to so there will be no user error when calling the function.

Comment: I'm certain this is a duplicate question, just looking for previous one now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your reports in a way that current `reportCategory` will define it's keys and then use below generic function to corresponding reports:

```
type reports = {
  'financial': 'financial workspaces' | 'financial datacenter',
  'operational': 'operational information' | 'operational environment',
  'security': 'security Accounts' | 'security needing attention'
}

function openReport<K extends keyof reports, V extends reports[K]>(category: K , report: V){

}

openReport('financial', 'financial datacenter');
openReport('financial', 'security Accounts'); // won't compile
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAThYHsbAM5QLxQN4CgpQHIAzASwDsBDMgYxIoBsCAuQ0ymu%20qAdyQGsUYCtQgoCUAD6tyVWgygATCsGEQywCDAIAaPIQSQYykgkqMWBA5uOn55IkgC2NsuKmXDL%20WoBuJGKaOasA6egQoENQArjAkoMyEEdGxoFAAgtTUCFHqYpKJkTFxIFBkEBAK5ADmUMoa6iauOAC%20ODhEOdTAjVBWZABK8EjAADwA0lAQAB71Cmh8ECAIRLBDyCjaUABqkzNqc6uI6wDaYwC6AHwAFNTKEFVIICwTm3BHwCxbAJS4LW19g3eV2IMg4DB00nYci4ShUInUmgIXwA3DgAWtgMC2LJOBDwoUUiUMlkcqgkcioAB6Sk8UwEYBQLKOMAkegQIA)

Comment: Surely there's a previous version of this question you could point to instead? We don't want SO to end up being a mass of the same question answered 150 times...

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this *without* modifying the original types like so:

```
const openReport = async <C extends ReportCategory>(
  catagory: C,
  report: Extract<
    FinancialReports | OperationalReports | SecurityReports, 
    `${C & {}}${string}`
  >
) => {}
```

We use a generic type `C` to store the `category` type.

`report` has to be a type from `FinancialReports | OperationalReports | SecurityReports` where `C` is a substring. To achieve this, we can use `Extract` in combination with a template literal type. We must *defer* inference here with `& {}` to make sure that `C` is inferred by `category`.

Usage:

```
openReport("financial", "financial datacenter")
openReport("financial", "operational information") // Error
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYHsBOwDCBDYEDmyQF4oByAMwEsA7dCgYzPQBsioAfYhSJTMhKp14gGcINAK5IyoIgChpoSFABilanUZxEKQVEKkVtegygB3ZAGtBYdDQiDmbPVQOMoAE0zWIFLEhnzoAPKc3Lzq8MjA2rocEFzAPHxQlCTIALYhFPbswfGhRl4AbmRIvKlewH7g0ADKIuKSIBoRUUJ1EqBQAII0NAii3nYCRMJi7SBQFBAQrpTYUJhY3gky0r0UgsBQMRRNKDrzgiC0UAA8qFAQAB6Lrtq7aJg4eAB8ABTSUFA0HrhIIABcUFQABoPlAkOEUICAKLXLg0YAnZRONQMe7aNhBWIZMKaSICWqjBro4FQAAGABIAN7nABkUCpAF9GdSNhIKNhGWTntIAJQ6Z4MxmyaTbe6vABE5BRhglpKl+lRbg8Nm8sQlvNFkB2kOAkulqll8picQSLmSaQyGqgAHobVBoUgSkggA)

Comment: ***Ugh***. That hurts. :-) Inventive, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yeah, I would probably also recommend the other answer. But at least it is possible :)

Comment: There has to be a previous question with the simple approach. I can't find it, but I'm still not great at finding TypeScript questions. Drives me nuts people just post answers rather than trying to stick with SO's system (however massively flawed that system is).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - You could close it with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter. It sure is similar in some way

Comment: The three top answers explain overloads, conditionals and the map approach. So pretty much everything is covered.