# Typescript type narrow function return value based on a parameter

Tags: typescript

Hello smart people of Stack Overflow!

Does anyone know how to make the following function work? Currently the output is not being type narrowed based on the `brand` input.

The goal is for return value of `carFactory` to return a typed object based on the `brand` input.

```
type ToyotaCar = {
  brand: 'toyota'
  isCool: true
}

type LamboCar = {
  brand: 'lambo'
  isAwesome: false
}

type FordCar = {
  brand: 'ford'
  isFast: false
}

type Car = ToyotaCar | LamboCar | FordCar

type CarFactoryOptions = Partial<Car> & Pick<Car, 'brand'>

const mockToyota: ToyotaCar = { brand: 'toyota', isCool: true }
const mockLambo: LamboCar = { brand: 'lambo', isAwesome: false }
const mockFord: FordCar = { brand: 'ford', isFast: false }

const carFactory = (options: CarFactoryOptions) => {
  const { brand, ...overrides } = options
  switch (brand) {
    case 'toyota':
      return { ...mockToyota, ...overrides }

    case 'ford':
      return { ...mockFord, ...overrides }

    case 'lambo':
      return { ...mockLambo, ...overrides }

    default:
      throw new Error('')
  }
}

const ford = carFactory({ brand: 'ford' })
ford.isFast
```

I tried setting an explicit return type in a few different ways such as

`const carFactory = (options: CarFactoryOptions): Car & {typeof options['brand']} => {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript function return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)