# How to create a return type of object from an array of string?

Tags: typescript

I have a type and a function that accepts an array of keys of the aforementioned type(selector array). I want to do something to anotate the return type.

```
type MyType = {
  x: number;
  y: string;
  z: number;
};

const someFunc = (select: (keyof MyType)[]) => {
  return someval as (some_ts_wizardry)
};

//example
someFunc(['x', 'y']);
// return type { x: number; y: string; }
```

Is it possible to do this?

Edit:
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter) doesn't answer the question. If you would read it, it will become quite clear that suggesting that would be the dumbest thing that you can do today.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript function return type based on input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)

Comment: Looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpjEzw)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that.

Type information is known at compile time, after that it is erased.

Arguments passed to your function are not known at compile time. Your array could come from an API call for instance. As such TS cannot infer the return type.

What you can do is to use generics:

```
type MyType = {
  x: number;
  y: string;
  z: number;
};

const someFunc = <T extends keyof MyType> (select: (keyof MyType)[]): Pick<MyType, T> => {
  return {} as Pick<MyType, T>
};

//example
const res = someFunc<'x' | 'y'>(['x', 'y']);
//     ^?
```

Here's a playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoA8BcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4DcWUIBAzsFQJaEDmd2AXgSQrU6AXzoYAxgHtCLKEymkIAMWKEJUVAB54UCDmARCAEyZQA1hBBSAZrARIAfFAAUTCABsIE4AReXrOzhESABKAG0AXVCCAAU2CXMtYKQAGih4Z2RnTGwqCGBiKkJ0ESgAQzN4xOSHSHTMjDEMDAB6Vv1y0jAvSRk5fLNUBSVVdS0AchwJqAAfKAmQCccXcKmJ9MWJ6Lp27H2APQB+DCA)

Comment: Understood. Is there a way to implement something like what you seen in Sequalize's or mongoDB's project function? I earlier tried to cast the given array to `const` and then do something with it, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This problem seems like something that should be possible but I am not sure if it is.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Though the `<'x' | 'y'>` after function call was not required. I didn't know about this utility type. Thank you for your answer. I learnt something new. :}

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)
[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoA8BcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4DcWUIBAzsFQJaEDmd2AXgSQrU6AXzoZQkKAGsIIJlFSyQAewBmsBEnEBjFYRZQmK0hABixQjsVQAPPCgQcwCIQAmC5UwB8ACiYQADYQOsAE8ADaALoAlIre6PRUEMDEVIToUCJQAIYKAApsOtK2cIiQADRQ8N4YYhgYxqYWVr4RAOQ47VXtIO2xNEA)

```
type MyType = {
  x: number;
  y: string;
  z: number;
};

type keys = keyof MyType;

const someFunc = <T extends keys>(select: T[]) => {
  return { } as Pick<MyType, T>
};

someFunc(['x', 'y']);
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are answered by the answer to other questions. Flag them as duplicates.