# Typescript. Return different objects type depending on enum input argument

Tags: typescript, enums, narrowing

I have template names enum and for each enum value function `fetchTemplate` must return it's own response type.

```js
enum KeyEnum {
  VK = 'VK',
  VIBER = 'VIBER',
}

type VkResponse = { vk: string };
type ViberResponse = { viber: number };

type ReturnTypes = {
  [KeyEnum.VK]: VkResponse;
  [KeyEnum.VIBER]: ViberResponse;
};
```

I have created function `fetchTemplate` with this signature:

```js
const fetchTemplate = <T extends KeyEnum>(key: T): ReturnTypes[T]
```

And with this body :

```js
const fetchTemplate = <T extends KeyEnum>(key: T): ReturnTypes[T] => {
  if (key === KeyEnum.VK) {
    return { vk: 'someString' }; <<- Here i got TS2322 error (description below)
  }

  if (key === KeyEnum.VIBER) {
    return { viber: 1 } as ReturnTypes[T]; <<- No problems, but i dont want use "as"
  }
};

# Unnecessary type definition in the left, just for testing
const vkRes: VkResponse = fetchTemplate(KeyEnum.VK);
const viberRes: ViberResponse = fetchTemplate(KeyEnum.VIBER);
```

But in the function body i can't just return `{vk: 'someString'}` or `{viber:1}`, because i got TS2322:

> TS2322:
> Type  { vk: string; }  is not assignable to type ReturnTypes[T]
> Type  { vk: string; }  is not assignable to type  VkResponse & ViberResponse
> Property  viber  is missing in type  { vk: string; }  but required in type ViberResponse

Why TypeScript can't do type narrowing in this case? Why i need to use "as ReturnTypes[T]", how to avoid it? How i can correctly narrow `key` type from `T` to specific `.VK` or `.VIBER` and explicitly define certain (not union) return type in IFs blocks?

> TypeScript v5.2.2
> Node v20.8.0

This one also not working:

```
  switch (key) {
    case KeyEnum.VIBER:
      return { viber: 1 }; <<- The same TS2322 error
  }
```

Comment: Can you check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter

Maybe this will helps...

Comment: @Mina- i have checked i think all of same questions, but didn't found solution for my case, all other cases like `T extends "first" ? FirstType :
    T extends "second" ? SecondType :`. i don't like this structure, because i think it is not necessary and code can be clearly and more compact.

Comment: This happens due to a missing feature in TS; see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  The way to fix it is to refactor to an indexed access, possibly using accessors so that you're not pre-calculating every possible output; like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbyVBN).  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks! I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, sometime in the next hour, probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently [control-flow based narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (like `switch`/`case` or `if`/`else` blocks) does not play nicely with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  The problem is that while checking `key === KeyEnum.VK` will narrow the type of `key`, it will *not* affect the generic *type parameter* (`T` in your example).  This is considered a missing feature, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  Until and unless that is implemented, you'll need to work around it.

For now if you want to use a generic function and return an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like `ReturnTypes[T]`, you'll need to actually perform an indexing operation: that is, get an object of type `ReturnTypes`, and read a property at the key of type `T`.  Conceptually for your example that looks like:

```
const fetchTemplate = <T extends KeyEnum>(key: T): ReturnTypes[T] => {
  return {
    [KeyEnum.VK]: { vk: 'someString' },
    [KeyEnum.VIBER]: { viber: 1 }
  }[key]
}; // okay
```

One possible problem with this is that it requires you to pre-calculate every possible return value.  If you call `fetchTemplate(KeyEnum.VK)`, the object will still evaluate `{viber: 1}` and then throw it away.  For a simple case like this that's probably no big deal, but if your code has side-effects or is expensive to compute, then you could refactor to use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), so that only the relevant code gets run:

```
const fetchTemplate = <T extends KeyEnum>(key: T): ReturnTypes[T] => {
  return {
    get [KeyEnum.VK]() {
      return { vk: 'someString' };
    },
    get [KeyEnum.VIBER]() {
      return { viber: 1 };
    }
  }[key]
};
```

Here if you call `fetchTemplate(KeyEnum.VK)`, only the getter for `KeyEnum.VK` is never run.

Hopefully someday microsoft/TypeScript#33014 will be implemented, since this refactoring, while functional, is potentially confusing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBRc0DeBYAUFKA1GUAvFAOT4kA0WOuAkgEKIBKRpdjTlWAvllgC7wADsDwBrJsADOQgPYgpo4qigA3MQC4oU-gCcAliADmUbgG4Bw0bn0AjYLskz5i1itV2HWlPd2mLmJYiUJL8YLogACpWUm7UUADacEgoAHT4ALpauBLScgrAAThJCMiQ6QzMWXiejnkuhTwBfJgAxi78UABmwPytABaRwBBCADYAhvzAAAysADyRUMAAHlMgACaxyWUQAHwAFGIIWpEAlFqh4VExCZEZRLtQGNhQur1XT-HF22mZWu6aUhSWQQYAAZT0hiMJFMVBe31Kv0qTGq7lqWgAjKZ4twEkd4Bkmi12gpOj0+oNhmNJkooAslqtQJtYIjIAd8SdziF3hFoiIpLd7oRHs8cG8whFPvCoEZeokfuVMvtTlKcGrXjyQE81ICSMDQRCDMYYeYvrCzbLOiUUorkRllar1RqJVq0b5Mf4zbwXrj8YTMKbAm0OjqnNlcs4CqxyQMhiMJlN9gqIOkYKcAiSdGpamGar4nPlXMQY5T4zSk6yU+xmOmsEA)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably looking for is [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) which in your case will look like this:

```
enum KeyEnum {
  VK = 'VK',
  VIBER = 'VIBER',
}

type VkResponse = {vk: string};
type ViberResponse = {viber: number};

function fetchTemplate(key: KeyEnum.VIBER): ViberResponse;
function fetchTemplate(key: KeyEnum.VK): VkResponse;
function fetchTemplate(key: KeyEnum) {
  if (key === KeyEnum.VK) {
    return { vk: 'someString' };
  }

  if (key === KeyEnum.VIBER) {
    return { viber: 1 }
  }
}

const vkRes: VkResponse = fetchTemplate(KeyEnum.VK);
const viberRes: ViberResponse = fetchTemplate(KeyEnum.VIBER);
```

Comment: I forgot to tell about ‘function’ overloads, they are not suitable, the code style does not allow using ‘function’, only arrow functions.

Comment: @Mauzzz0 What’s the rationale behind this decision?

Comment: @Valentin idk, it was before me, and i just need to hold it

Comment: It's the first time I've heard of such a rule. Not using classic functions can be a problem: for example, [assertion functions cannot be written as arrow functions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34523). If no one knows why, this rule should probably be revisited.