# Generic type can't assume a default value for a union literal

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a function to search online or offline for a given term. I want to provide the user with a switcher to let them decide where the function should search, and for each path, a different object will be returned. The default path is online.

I followed this idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54166010) to develop my code, and you can see my current code approach in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKwCGUDGALAcUwFtgAlYAZwFcAbeAXjgG8AoOOSrXPAFWCjEAXJxhQAlgDsA5gBp2cKFToxKIiACMAVsBwwA2gF15HMJmlTMMcREnrtumKwC+rVqEiwEyVBmz4AdTwBVCYAcltaKWAwuAAfOAiAMySAWijJGIBuNw9oeCQUdG58AHlJDOBSsGtbSjgmNlNzYAB+EUlqYg0BHNd3cHzvIr8eIlJq2slKAB5eUfwAGQgcKxtJOFAYYEkAE3qFvCCQgD4GlgUAd2ClEXmSvGXVqb64ADJi-zxyysn1yhyA08BR8cFKKUqhwoNHo5wAglAoJhEDMmnBpCRgABJXYiShiKTSHIcDGkABymLxBJkfROgLyXkKvge42Ac0OTzWtk2IG2ewOD2OSjOTAU9y+nKmPL5+0SkWisVanzGmOhKjgIjFHJWXI2Wx2suSaUqirBEOiUOUsI6wAAbr03EChjg6vAuF9WedMJREJIcOyHpL1tKDQKvkLgCcABQKUnAXjiGC0YBUiQyWRwBQQGr-ESHVl-OoBiU6qYilhwa4hERG9IKjNmaQpuAABjgrgAlCIAApQCDEcRcGb5zHFnhB2wnEVnNHiJJwKPZqaUVoAOirSneHyX-3XN1CDHC8syYQ7Fw4HAA9NfOA84MfgAoOEoYNQoBte-3B8BV0pKBBaHtKNmGcOBvWVfBWTHJZS3WE4O2Jds3CvG93R4e9zUyBQXzfD8+wHLhfyoACgJAsCwxVUhoMeWDJwQlw3GvS84AAUXARxgF2StkQQCA4GoLgEGCOAkmoP0plYF1pngCBqBgMA5PONDIMxKMACIaBQKA4GIbAbDUs8b0TTg8Fk2guMgKR4A0RA4F2YAkkwdUYD4iIKnrOA5zgRBZLgUz7W04yfOoStxFoWhb1QAADKT8XvOSFJgHt8O-YcWVVK14AScEkkhB41XoE4oqE1APA4riejwTBbRsQL6hi114vkuSACZkq-IcR1IAqYCKtxYpkhLWqU9LSHUzSBB0vSIDUjNmErfcawgFI6xPdtDOYskIEuOAsW4yR4A8KIcETWhbJckSpC45bcuiDN9z8iAAsJTz4GC0LwsiuAGukprErauBPwItkcryr4er6oA). Opening the link, you will see something like this:

[image]

Reproducible example:

```
export type SearchGameResult = {
  searchTerm: string,
  results: object[],
  pagination: object
}

export type SearchWhere = 'online' | 'off-line';

export type SearchOnlineOptions = {
  page?: number;
}

export type SearchGameOptions<TSearchLocation extends SearchWhere> = {
  where: TSearchLocation;
} & SearchOnlineOptions;

export type OfflineSearchResult = Array<{
  gameId: string;
  gameName: string;
}>;

export type SearchGame<TSearchLocation extends SearchWhere> = 
  TSearchLocation extends 'online' ? SearchGameResult : 
  TSearchLocation extends 'off-line' ? OfflineSearchResult : never;


export const searchGame = async<TSearchLocation extends SearchWhere>(
  gameTitle: string, 
  // The problem is here in the `where` parameter
  options: SearchGameOptions<TSearchLocation> = { where: 'off-line', page: 0 }
): Promise<SearchGame<TSearchLocation>> => {
  if (options?.where && options.where === 'online') {
    /// search online
    return Promise.resolve({} as SearchGame<TSearchLocation>);
  }

  /// search offline
  return Promise.resolve({} as SearchGame<TSearchLocation>);
}

/// Expected way to use the function
const output = searchGame("super mario") // it should point by default to 'online', if you hover it you will see `const output: Promise<SearchGameResult | OfflineSearchResult>` the expected behavior is `const output2: Promise<SearchGameResult>`

const output2 = searchGame("super mario", { where: 'off-line' }) // Now I want explicitly to find offline, here hovering it you will see `const output2: Promise<OfflineSearchResult>`
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't the `where` parameter initialized as `'online'`?

Comment: Please put a [mre] directly in the question.

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz; in other words, there is no way.

Yes, your answer addresses my question completely.